# How to specify an integer array as generic in VHDL?

Tags: generics, instantiation, vhdl

I am trying to create a generic driver for an SPI based IO expander. The idea is to pass initialization values in the instantiation, that matches the requested IO setup.

My current attempt look like this :

```
entity max7301_simple is
   generic ( 
        IO_cfg : array (1 to 7) OF integer range 0 to 255 := (16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#)
           );
     port  (
        -- Application interface :
        clk_i       :   in std_logic;        -- input clock, xx MHz.
        rst_i       :   in std_logic;        -- sync reset.
        en_i        :   in std_logic;        -- enable, forces re-init of pins on MAX7301.
        output_i    :   in std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);   --data to write to output pins on MAX7301
        irq_o       :   out std_logic;       -- IRQ, TODO: what triggers, change on inputs ?
        input_o     :   out std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);  --data read from input pins on MAX7301
        -- MAX7301 SPI interface
        sclk        :   out std_logic;        -- SPI clock
        din         :   in std_logic;        -- SPI data input
        dout        :   out std_logic;       -- SPI read data
        cs          :   out std_logic        -- SPI chip select
    );
end max7301_simple;
```

The problem is with the IO_cfg array, i have tried various attempts w/wo init values etc. And cannot seem to figure how to specify the array.

I belive to have read that you can pass an array as generic, but still haven't got much luck with it.  Xilinx ISE just tells med "syntax error near 'array' " wich is not informative enough to get me forward.

Any help would be appreciated

I always need 7 values, when instantiating this module.

Answer (score 8):

You are allowed to use an array as a generic parameter however you are not allowed to *declare* it there, on-the-fly as an anonymous type.

You have to first declare your integer array type in a separate package (which can be in the same file or in a separate one) and then `use` the package in your entity and when you instantiate it.

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
-- package declaration
package mytypes_pkg is

     type my_array_t is array (1 to 7) of integer range 0 to 255;

end package mytypes_pkg;

-- entity "uses" the package   
use work.mytypes_pkg.all;

entity max7301_simple is
   generic ( 
        IO_cfg : my_array_t := (16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#, 16#55#)
           );
   -- ports [...]
end max7301_simple;
```

Be careful to also `use`the package in the architecture that instantiates your entity.

---

(Optional reading)

**Why is it really a *syntax error* to write it like you did?**

Looking at the VHDL grammar in the [VHDL (2002) standard](http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~szamani/1076%20Ieee%20Standard%20Vhdl%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf), each generic parameter's declaration is a `interface_constant_declaration` and you have the following grammar rules:

```
[§ 4.3.2]
interface_constant_declaration ::=  
            [ constant ] identifier_list : [ in ] subtype_indication [ := static_expression ]

[§ 4.2]
subtype_indication ::= 
            [ resolution_function_name ] type_mark [ constraint ]
```

The type reference can only be the name of an existing type (`type_mark`) or the restriction of an existing type.

Answer (score 5):

I propose a bit more generic approach by using **2008 VHDL** standard and predefined attributes - this allows **passing an array of any length**.
Define your type in your package like this:

```
package data_types is
    type array_of_integers is array(natural range <>) of integer;
end package;
```

Now in your code pass generic array as follows:

```
generic(
    COEFFICIENTS : array_of_integers := (-1, 0, 1)
);
```

Now software will be using a default indexing scheme. It can be taken into account with predetermined **'left**
attribute (reference can be found at: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html):

```
-- First coefficient
    ... <= COEFFICIENTS(COEFFICIENTS'left);
-- Second coefficient
    ... <= COEFFICIENTS(COEFFICIENTS'left + 1);
```

Generally you should use this array in some kind of **loop** or **generate** statement:

```
GENERATE_STATEMENT: for entry in 0 to COEFFICIENTS'length-1 generate
    out(entry) <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(COEFFICIENTS(COEFFICIENTS'left + entry), out(entry)'length));
end generate;
```

As a little side note for **Quartus II** users - it is also possible to use generic arrays in **.bdf** schematic files. Set parameter type to **Auto** and rewrite parameter value in this format - ***A(D"-1", D"0", D"1")***, where ***D*** stands for **decimal data type** (Useful link: http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/assign/asd/asd_tab_param.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a less-constrained generic, you can do:

```
generic (IO_cfg : integer_vector);
```

As long as you have a VHDL-2008 compiler.

Comment: Indeed [VHDL-2008](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/#composite) defines array type (natural range) for boolean, integer, real and time types. However VHDL-2008 support is still very limited, at least in the tools I use (ModelSim, QuartusII).

Comment: @wap26: "very limited" is a bit strong.  MOdelsim supports most of it now, Aldex supports everything.  Altera and Xilinx support quite a large amount.  Type/package generics seem to be the worst aspect.  `integer_vector` is supported in 2008 mode for all the tools I'm aware of.

Comment: ok, thanks for the fresh news. I'll check the latest version of my tools!