# Variable number of inputs and outputs in VHDL

Tags: generics, vhdl

I should create an entity in VHDL that has a variable number of inputs and outputs. This number of pins should be given from the GENERIC construct. Let's suppose to have this code:

```
entity HELLO is
    GENERIC(NUM_INPUT: integer:=4;
            NUM_OUTPUT: integer:=2
     );

    port(
         input1 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         input2 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         input3 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         input4 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         out1   : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
         out2   : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) 

     );
end entity HELLO;
```

Obviously, writing them manually(as in example above) make the GENERIC construct useless.

I want that this 4 inputs and 2 outputs are automatically generated in accordance with GENERIC info. How to do?

Comment: Your entity header has an extra semicolon in the port clause following the `out2` interface element declaration. Semicolons are used as interface element delimiters in an interface list. Pragmatically this allows a single lexical element (token) look ahead in parsing to determine where the end of the interface list occurs, branching either on a semicolon or the closing right parenthesis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use generic parameter as port array length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213734/use-generic-parameter-as-port-array-length)

Comment: Corrected, was a distraction fault

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to define a custom array type for your 32 bit word in a package, something like:

```
type WORD_ARRAY_type is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
```

your entity declaration then becomes:

```
use work.HELLOPackage.all;

entity HELLO is
GENERIC (
  NUM_INPUT : integer := 4;
  NUM_OUTPUT : integer := 2
);
port (
  input1 : in WORD_ARRAY_type(NUM_INPUT-1 downto 0);
  out1   : out WORD_ARRAY_type(NUM_OUTPUT-1 downto 0)
);
end entity HELLO;
```

You could also use unconstrained arrays for the input and output:

```
entity HELLO is
GENERIC (
  NUM_INPUT : integer := 4;
  NUM_OUTPUT : integer := 2
);
port (
  input1 : in WORD_ARRAY_type;
  out1   : out WORD_ARRAY_type
);
end entity HELLO;
```

then work with these ports using the generics. When instantiating the entity, simply connect an array with the right dimensions to match the generics.