# Creating VHDL Multiplexer with variable width and number of inputs

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am trying to create a bus/dataflow multiplexer with variable width and number of inputs, and use it as an IP Module in block design with Vivado. So far I have successfully managed to create a 2to1 mux with variable width:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mux is
  Generic ( NUM_BITS : integer);
  Port ( 
    SEL : in STD_LOGIC;
    A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUM_BITS-1 downto 0);
    B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUM_BITS-1 downto 0);
    X : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUM_BITS-1 downto 0));
end mux;

architecture Behavioral of mux is

begin
    X <= A when (SEL = '0') else B;
end Behavioral;
```

This works. I am able to drop this into the Block Design tool in Vivado, and I am able to customize the block and change the value of "NUM_BITS".

[Customizable IP Mux in Block Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6okf.png)

I have almost successfully created a variable input mux with fixed width:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
package my_pkg is
 -- Generic ( NUM_BITS : integer);
  type inputs is array(natural range<>) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
end my_pkg;

library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use work.my_pkg.all;
entity mux is
  Generic ( SEL_WIDTH : integer);
  Port ( 
    SEL : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SEL_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    INPUT : in inputs(0 downto 2**SEL_WIDTH-1);
    OUTPUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0));
end mux;

architecture Behavioral of mux is

begin
    OUTPUT <= INPUT(to_integer(unsigned(SEL)));
end Behavioral;
```

However, I am not able to drop this into the block design tool because port type needs to be std_logic_vector in order to be recognized by the block design tool.

[Block Design Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vps4a.png)

I have seen some other posts addressing similar issues:

[Using array of std_logic_vector as a port type, with both ranges using a generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468334/using-array-of-std-logic-vector-as-a-port-type-with-both-ranges-using-a-generic) - unable to use the provided examples in block design tool

[Use generic parameter as port array length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213734/use-generic-parameter-as-port-array-length) - used this to create the code in second portion

But neither of these helped me achieve what I would like.
I would like to combine these two into one multiplexer with BOTH variable inputs and width.
I am using Xilinx Vivado 2020.1

Comment: Block design tools are generally rather limiting. You'll have much more success simply using HDL.

Comment: As this question is specific to Xilinx Vivado, you might have more luck asking it on the [Xilinx Community Forum](https://forums.xilinx.com/).